# Access Electron in Cordova

Tags: cordova, electron, cordova-plugins

I was wondering if there is any way to access Electron when developing an app with Cordova. For example to provide some desktop-specific functions like minimizing and maximizing the window, or any other functions that electron object provides by its API, Remote or IPC.